# How to write RegEx which starts and ends on different lines, these lines include one matching word only inside

Tags: regex, notepad++, regular-language

I want to replace a code group of 3 lines on the same file and on other fi
les by using notepad++ find & replace feature with regular expressions (regex) 
Only thing in common on these lines which i want to select is they include the same word "mailicon4.gif" on the last line, and i want to select all the last line, and i want that the selection starts with "a class=" tag which comes 2-3 lines earlier. I copied the part i want to select with find and replace with "" to delete it.

I already tried such a code for example:
?maili.?$\R

It selects the last paragraph but doesn't start with the last "

```
    <a class="nonblock nontext" id="u209382" href="mailto:info@example.com">
      <!-- rasterized frame --><img class="temp_no_img_src" id="u209382_img" alt="" width="66" height="66"
        data-orig-src="images/mailicon4-u209382.png?crc=143036675" src="images/mailicon4.gif?crc=4208392903" /></a>
```

Comment: Can you make your target text more specific?  It is somewhat vague/open right now.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239) HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  the code part, which i want to select and replace is exactly which i pasted above, i want my regex code capture all these 3 lines starting with "<a class=" and ends with "</a>"     and only word in common is "maili" on the last line of these 3 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<a (?:(?!</a>).)*mailicon4\.gif.*?</a>`
- Replace with: `$1`     # a space then $1
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Explanation:**

```
<a                  # start tag
(?:(?!</a>).)*      # 0 or more any character, but not </a>
mailicon4\.gif      # literally
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</a>                # literally
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x5NWmg/1)